# Continiuous functions to the sphere

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X=AUB$ be  a  topological space and $A, B$ be a two closed set of X. Let $f:A\to S^n$ and $g:B\to S^m$ be two continuous functions. Define $h:X\to S^{n+m+1}$ by
$$h(x)=(f(x),0,\cdots , 0) \text{if} x\in{A\setminus B}$$
$$h(x)=(f(x),0, g(x)) \text{if} x\in{A\cap B}$$
$$h(x)=(0,\cdots ,0, g(x)) \text{if} x\in{B\setminus A}$$
Is $h$ continuous?

Comment: Do you have an extra zero?  Is this function well defined on $A\cap B$?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

At first I remark that n-dimensional sphere $S^n$ is not an $n$-th power of 1-dimesional sphere $S^1$, so the coordinatewise definition of the map $h$ is incorrect. Moreover, if we define in such the manner a function $h$ from the space $X$ into a power of a some space $S$, then the function $h$ will be not necessarily continuous, because the composition $\pi\circ h:X\to S^n$ (where $\pi:S^{n+m+1}\to S^n$ is the projection onto) is equal to $f$ on $A$ and is equal to $0$ outside $A$.

Comment: I think that the answer depends on how the constructed fuction should be related with the functions $f$ and $g$.